# Cannot open APK file from Download folder Android C#

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, apk, android-fileprovider

I've Looked through all other example questions and their answers to this problem I can find to no success, I believe the issue is that the MediaProvier/Intent call cannot access the Download folder, in the device log there are MediaProvider errors stating the file path cannot be found and an EACCES permission error.

I have permissions to READ/WRITE external storage and REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES persmissions

The device emulator shows 'There was a problem parsing the package'
What am I doing wrong and why can I not open/install the APK file? Any help would be appreciated.

In my opinion if I was to copy the apk to a path within the internal directory rather than external then this would work, however I also cannot copy the apk to any Android/data/ location using adb due to permissions issue.

```
Java.IO.File path = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads);
        Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(path, "test2.apk");

        // Get URI and MIME type of file
        Android.Net.Uri uri = FileProvider.GetUriForFile(context, AppInfo.PackageName + ".fileprovider", file);
        String mime = context.ContentResolver.GetType(uri);

        // Open file with user selected app
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionView);
        intent.SetDataAndType(uri, mime);
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantWriteUriPermission);
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantPersistableUriPermission);
        //context.StartActivity(intent);

        Intent chooser = Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "Update");
        chooser.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);

        IList<Android.Content.PM.ResolveInfo> resInfoList = context.PackageManager.QueryIntentActivities(chooser, Android.Content.PM.PackageInfoFlags.MatchDefaultOnly);

        foreach (Android.Content.PM.ResolveInfo resolveInfo in resInfoList)
        {
            String packageName = resolveInfo.ActivityInfo.PackageName;
            context.GrantUriPermission(packageName, uri, ActivityFlags.GrantWriteUriPermission | ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
        }

        context.StartActivity(chooser);
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="31" />
<application android:label="DRIVER" android:theme="@style/MainTheme" android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
    <provider android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>
</application>
```

XML File:

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<external-path
    name="external"
    path="." />
<external-files-path
  name="external_files"
  path="." />
<files-path
    name="files"
    path="." />
<external-files-path name="my_images" path="Pictures" />
<external-files-path name="my_movies" path="Movies" />|
```

Device error logs:

```
12-21 19:18:50.371  pixel_5_-_api_30    Warning 13637   InstallStaging  java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithFileNotFoundExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:151)
    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProviderNative.java:781)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1983)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1798)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:1475)
    at com.android.packageinstaller.InstallStaging$StagingAsyncTask.doInBackground(InstallStaging.java:174)
    at com.android.packageinstaller.InstallStaging$StagingAsyncTask.doInBackground(InstallStaging.java:167)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:394)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:305)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
12-21 19:18:50.371  pixel_5_-_api_30    Warning 13637   InstallStaging  Error staging apk from content URI
12-21 19:18:50.370  pixel_5_-_api_30    Error   1332    MediaProvider   Couldn't find file: /storage/emulated/0/Download/test2.apk
```

Comment: You did not tell what you want. And starting with 'tried similar' does not make any sense if you did not yet tell anything. Please try again ;-)

Comment: had to edit both them comment to get just right ay... @blackapps

Comment: Nothing right. The intro of your post is unreadable as you dont tell where it is sbout and what your problem is. Read!

Comment: the errors occur from startActivity, this solution is the same as shown on stackoverflow in other post answers @blackapps

Comment: Soo glad to say that I've managed to sort this issue myself now, ill still say thanks anyway.... even though you where 0 help. Will post answer when it allows me to @blackapps

Comment: wasteman @blackapps